# How is the fn key in written in vimscript?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

How do I map the <kbd>fn</kbd> key in combination with another key to a macro? I know that the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key in key combinations is written as a `C` (e.g., `<C-c>` for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) in vimscript.

So how would I do something similar to this but for <kbd>fn</kbd>?

Comment: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can map `fn` key in vim since it's mostly hooked in global os level.

I've managed to remap my `fn` key using software like [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)

Comment: I cannot use karabiner because it only works on macOS and I use Arch Linux. What would be an equivalent program for Linux?

Comment: @coder54321 Consider asking about keyboard mappings in Linux on either [Superuser](https://superuser.com) or [unix.se]